# I want a container in my app to work like the snap grid in windows works on the desktop

Tags: java, xml, swing, jtable, drag

In the iphone UI or windows desktop if you move an app to another position on the screen it shifts apps backwards or forwards based on where the app was placed. I would like to have this functionality in a java app but using a mouse and jtables would be drug in a jpanel and reordered in the same way.

I also need the program to know the order of the jtables as it will save the layout into an xml file.

I am not really sure where to begin as i have never done anything this complicated.

Comment: You may begin by drawing us a picture of the GUI as you want it behave.  I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish from your description.

Comment: So on the widows desktop if you move an icon above another it snaps it in place and pushes other icons down. This is essentially what i want it to do.